# Can't install Jitsi meet on Lubuntu

Tags: software-installation, dpkg, lubuntu

I'm using Lubuntu 19.10 and I want to install jitsi meet.
I followed these steps: https://jitsi.org/downloads/ubuntu-debian-installations-instructions/. Which are:

`wget -qO - https://download.jitsi.org/jitsi-key.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -`

then

`sudo sh -c "echo 'deb https://download.jitsi.org stable/' > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jitsi-stable.list"`

then

`sudo apt-get -y update`

and finally

`sudo apt-get -y install jitsi-meet`

However, I get the following errors at the end of the process:

```
dpkg: error processing package jitsi-meet-web-config (--configure):
 installed jitsi-meet-web-config package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 jitsi-meet-web-config
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: It might be worth looking at the official instructions on their github https://github.com/jitsi/jitsi-meet/blob/master/doc/quick-install.md

Comment: ok I did it, but I get the exact same error.